# OpenCV/numpy: Quickly comparing a large number of contour objects using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I have a number of contour objects identified from a z-stack of 1024x1024 microscopy images. Each z-step contains approximately 10000-40000 contours. Contours are on average 4 pixels.

What I am trying to do is determine which contours exist on multiple z-planes (they touch each other when the images are overlaid) and what their 3-Dimensional area is. I can accomplish this (approximately) but the code is extremely slow and extremely memory heavy (I am topping out a 32GB RAM computer).

My current approach is as follows:

1. Dump all internal points of each contour into a massive list and make an indexing list to go along with it.
2. Do a binary comparison of x and y something like:

   ```
   x_intersections=np.array(np.equal(np.matrix(z1[:,0]).T,z2[:,0]))
   y_intersections=np.array(np.equal(np.matrix(z1[:,1]).T,z2[:,1]))
   intersections=x_intersections*y_intersections
   ```
3. Reindex to original lists to determine which points match across Z-steps.
4. Determine volume.

I'm mostly curious about step 2, is an faster way to do this? I've tried using sparse arrays or running each contour one at a time using `np.in1d()` and neither seemed to run faster. I've tried OpenCVs built in point comparison tool previously and it did not seem to be very fast.

Also, is there a way to not have to pull a 40000x40000 matrix into RAM (as it takes a lot of RAM) is there a rational and fast way to subsection these lists? Is there a clever way to use numpy to operate on parts of an array instead of the whole array at once? Is there an efficient way to dump from RAM onto a disk temporarily? This would allow me to run it on more computers simultaneously which cuts down on the run time considerably.

Is this a problem that would benefit from AutoJIT from numba? Or Blaze? Or pypy? Is there a similar tool I don't know about that would work here?

More broadly, am I doing something silly here? Is my approach the wrong way to frame this problem?

I have something like 20 z-steps, 3 channels, and 100+ images sometimes so even code that takes 10 seconds per comparison will end up taking an hour per image (about where I have it now). I can spread it across some servers to speed it up but I'd really like to get it down as much as possible.

Here is some python code to model the approximate situation:

```
z1=[]
i=0
while i<20000:
    temp=np.array([[[1,1]],[[1,2]],[[2,1]],[[2,2]]])+np.round(np.random.rand(1,1,2)*1024)
    z1.append(temp.astype(int))
    i+=1
z2=z1[1:10000]
i=0
while i<10000:
    temp=np.array([[[1,1]],[[1,2]],[[2,1]],[[2,2]]])+np.round(np.random.rand(1,1,2)*1024)
    z2.append(temp.astype(int))
    i+=1
random.shuffle(z2)
```

(My contours are not all length 4 some are more some are less, but this should be close enough to demo)

I then dump them as arrays by the approximate code:

```
output=(0,0)
index_list=(0,0)
for itemsN,items in enumerate(z1):
    output=np.vstack([output,items.squeeze()])
    index_list=np.vstack([index_list,np.ones((len(items),1))*itemsN])
output=np.delete(output,0,0)
index_list=np.delete(index_list,0)
```

I then use the code listed above in step 2 to cast the lists together (This is the part that is slow and is a massive memory hog, it will likely cause a memory error if you run it) and use the index list to figure out the contour pairs that belong together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are some suggestions (based on my understanding of your question. If this is not what you wanted, let me know).

1. To compare two contours, you can use [`cv2.matchShapes()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes) function in OpenCV.
2. Or you can calculate some features of all contours like area, perimeter, centroid etc. Then compare them first. Only if they match, compare the whole contours. Two contours with same centroid and area will, most probably, be same contours, so you can compare those contours as a whole, others you can neglect which will give you some speed up.

Comment: This worked I compared the centroids to pre-sort the lists into smaller subsets before doing pixel by pixel comparison. Thanks!